# Cannot seem to pass argument to Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, parameter-passing

in Python, I am calling a google apps script with the following code:

```
#Create an execution request object.
    request = {"function": "getFoldersUnderRoot", "parameters": [3]}
# Make the API request.
    response = service.scripts().run(body=request, scriptId=SCRIPT_ID).execute()
```

However in my script, I don't seem to be able to access the argument value (in my case 3).

the script looks like:

```
function getFoldersUnderRoot(tc) {
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folders = root.getFolders();
  var folderSet = {};
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderSet[folder.getId()] = folder.getName();
  }
  var Id = XXXX; 
  var dat = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Id);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(dat);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet.getRange("A3").setValue(tc);
  return folderSet;
}
```

and I get: "undefined" in cell A3.....   I am not really versed in JavaScript or Python...  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the Google Script code straight from the script bound to the sheet? If that gives you an error, you know that's where the issue is, otherwise it's with the Python part...

Answer (score 0):

`getRange()` must be called on a sheet not a spreadsheet so your line declaring the variable `sheet` needs to be changed to this

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
```

or you can use

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.... my bad...

I didn't realise you had to publish the google script after every change... saving it is not enough (ie the external program would still see the old version of the script)...

I wish I had realised this earlier!!

Comment: you don't need to if you add to your request 'devMode': True